# Is there a limit to the number of tables in a SQL Server database AND view?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, limit

I'm working with a database on SQL Server Standard edition that loads data every day - performance of the `SQLBulkInsert` is slowing down as the table grows and indexing I/O kicks in (even with disable/rebuild, its getting slower)

So, an alternative suggested to me was to create a view that references each one of the daily tables (or the last 30 for example).  Should just be a case of `SELECT * FROM x UNION ALL SELECT * FROM y...`

Is there a limit to the number of tables that can be included, or the length of the view definition?

AND
Is there a limit to the number of tables in a database?

OR - is there a better way to do this (without spending any money or I'd move to SQL Server Enterprise and use partitioned tables!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for limits, you can look at [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

As another option I would look at using [partitioned tables and partitioned indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx).

One of the important things to note here is

> The data of partitioned tables and indexes is divided into units that
>   can be spread across more than one filegroup in a database. The data
>   is partitioned horizontally, so that groups of rows are mapped into
>   individual partitions

Which basically states that you can spread the partitions accross various logical file groups. This should provide you with coniderable performance improvements.

Comment: Sorry, but partitioned tables are only in SQL Enterprise, and I am on Standard (and cannot upgrade) :(

Comment: I guess from the limits it's down to resources to manage the SELECT statement in the view, as opposed to any physical limit on tables/no of characters?

Comment: You haven't answered the question, nor does the linked resource have the answer.

Answer (score 16):

SQL Server doesn't have a table limit. Rather, it has an object limit (of which tables are a type of object). So, in effect, the sum of all objects (indexes, views, tables, procs, etc...) can't exceed 2 billion-ish (2,147,483,647 to be pedantic).

There is no hard limit to the amount of joins (or unions) you can have in a single query. The limitation will be hardware related.